# Can I expand the Logical Drive on an HP P410 live?

Tags: hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I have an HP Smart Array P410 w/FBWC with 4 drives configured as RAID-5.

Originally, I had 4 x 500meg drives, with 1 Logical Drive of 1.5T configured.

I have just swapped the 4x500MB drives for 4x4T drives.  I have swapped each one out in the RAID one at a time, giving the new drive time to rebuild before putting the next one in.

Now, I would like to extend my LD from 1.5T to 12T.

I believe I can issue the command:

```
hpacucli:  ctrl slot=4 ld 1 modify size=max
```

But I'm not sure if I can do that while my RAID is online, and if this can be done non-destructively.

Is there a way to extend my LD to be the full size?

Answer (score 0):

For those interested in this topic, the tool is now called ssacli. Here's a neat installation guide: https://gist.github.com/mrpeardotnet/a9ce41da99936c0175600f484fa20d03

The smart array logical drive expansion command is still the same:

```
ssacli ctrl slot=0 ld 2 modify size=max
```

Please be prepared to answer this:

```
Warning: Extension may not be supported on certain operating systems.
         Performing extension on these operating systems can cause data to
         become inaccessible. See SSA documentation for details. Continue?
         (y/n) y
```

Happy resizing!